# How to open command prompt in specific directory with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, command-line, notepad++, command-prompt

I need to open the command prompt programmatically but open it in a specifically directory.

In Notepad++ there is an option to open a file's directory in the command prompt.

[Here is what it looks like in Notepad++.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKjPT.jpg)

How would you do this?

Comment: There is this thing called Google that will hunt down answers to non questions like this.  Think of it as a research assistant.  When I Google your title I get **1.1 million hits** with **53,000** on this site alone.

Comment: Na really I'v never hear of that...

Comment: ...I have already Googled this exact problem and came up with naught. I would not post a question if I thought that I could find the answer through Google.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Open+cmd+in+specific+directory -- Second result, second answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks [VV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3740093/visual-vincent)

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this:

```
Const WorkingDirectory As String = "E:\Shared" ' the directory you want to be on
Dim exePath As String = Environment.SystemDirectory & "\cmd.exe"
Dim StartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(exePath)
Dim cmdSession As New Process

StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory ' start in this directory
StartInfo.Arguments = "/k" ' let cmd.exe remain running using /k
cmdSession.StartInfo = StartInfo

cmdSession.Start()
```

Regards, Paul